# using semaphore for process synchronization in multi threading producer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I'm learning `python` using one of my friends text books and I found the problem that in the following picture but I couldn't understand it or coding it could you help me :

" You are going to use the semaphores for process synchronization. Therefore, you are asked to develop a consumer and producer multithreaded program.

Let's assume, that we have a thread (producer, we will call it producectreacl) reading data (positive integer numbers) from the keyboard, entered by a user to be stored in an array (dynamic array). (Assume that the array can hold all numbers entered without overflow.) 
Another thread (consumer, we will call it consumer_thread) should read data from the array and write them into a file. This thread should run concurrently with the producer (procluse1).

Your program should make sure that the consumer thread can read from the array only after the producer thread has stored new data. Both threads will stop when the user enters a negative number.

Thereafter, another thread (teging.areacl) should start reading the array data as well as the file data and display them on the screen in order to verify if the consumer and producer have worked in a correctly synchronized fashion. This thread should not be synchronized with other threads, it useful for testing that consumer thread is synchronized with produce thread. "

And please notice that it's not a homework I'm self learner and programming not my main specialist and I couldn't writ a single line in this problem

Comment: Show the relevant code as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Same of course for relevant parts of other texts.

Comment: I edited the post to prevent any external link or images